# Rails - PSQL command line query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, psql

I'm trying to make an app in Rails 4 using psql database.

I've created three models for Project, Scope and Background.

The relationships between them are:

Project has one Scope
Scope has one Background, and belongs to Project
Background belongs to Scope

I can't figure out how to read the psql documentation. I have connected to the database and now want to search for background based on the project id.

My problems are:

1. I only know how to run one search in psql - that is SELECT * FROM "backgrounds"; I want to know how to search for a specific record in the background table
2. I don't have a project_id foreign key in my background table. I have a scope_id foreign key. However, I want to search for the project's background.

How do I search in psql, in the command line, for background, where project id = 5?

Thank you

Comment: I mostly find `psql` syntax to be pretty daunting to, so I either use `pgAdmin`, or, even better, in most cases I just start up the `rails console` and then query the database using activerecord, like you would in code.

Comment: Thanks Nathanvda, I'll give it a try in console. Does it seem strange to you that there is more than one record in the DB for each edit of a project?

Comment: Different question entirely, and a bit hard to answer without more background info. If you are using nested models, be sure to include the `:id` in the strong parameters section. If that is not the answer: create a different question and link it here :)

Comment: I'll try the :id - thanks, that might be my issue